# git diff and git difftool do nothing and give no output

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I am trying to get `git diff` to work on Windows 7 64 bit. When I run the following commands from a windows command prompt:

```
C:\temp\mygrit>git diff
```

or

```
C:\temp\mygrit>git difftool
```

I get no output and no external program launches. Here is my .gitconfig file:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

I get the same results if I remove all these lines from .gitconfig.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, simple answer. The default behaviour for `git diff` is to show the all files which have been modified but not staged. If you have no modified files then there is no output.

`git difftool` uses the output of `git diff` so if there's no output from the previous command `git difftool` will do nothing as well.

**Solution:** Change some files but don't stage them, re run the commands. If there are problems with your config file they will show up then.

Comment: `git diff --cached (or --staged)` : compares the files which are staged/indexed.

Comment: [`git diff --staged`: compares the files which are staged.](http://roman.st/Article/What-makes-Git-difficult-someone-coming-Mercurial)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is a very unnatural behaviour imho

Comment: [`git diff --no-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt) compares files ignoring their `git` status, just as some filesystem files